# How to Redirect non logged in user to login page when click on link in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to redirect user to login page when he clicks on Download link in wordpress:

```
<a href="http://localhost/proj/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/pdf-guide.pdf">Download</a>
```

and also i want to send e-mail if he login and click on download link.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can check user login or not using this simple if condition
 <?php if (is_user_logged_in()) {
            wp_redirect(get_site_url());
        }
?>   
 <?php  $redirect_url = get_site_url();

            $args = array(
                'echo' => true,
                'redirect' => $redirect_url,
                'form_id' => 'loginform',
                'label_username' => __('Email Address'),
                'label_password' => __('Password'),
                'label_remember' => __('Remember Me'),
                'label_log_in' => __('Log In'),
                'id_username' => 'user_login',
                'id_password' => 'user_pass',
                'id_remember' => 'rememberme',
                'id_submit' => 'wp-submit',
                'remember' => true,
                'value_username' => NULL,
                'value_remember' => false);

wp_login_form($args);

    ?>
1) You can put this code in your theme template file 
2) Create one page from admin side and select your template page.

You can call this page for login when user not log on.
you can call login page like site_url/login
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this plugin can help you.
https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/jonradio-private-site/

With this plugin you can make your site private. And only logged users can access to your download link . I dont know if you can make public the link if you make private the site.

Comment: Thanks for your help.But i don't want to make my website private.Is any other idea?